# How could I make my program find the adresses manually?

Tags: c++, memory-address, cheat-engine

I am making a hack in c++ for a roblox game(Counter Blox Roblox Offensive) and my program just changes the in-game money but when I restart my the game and run it again and start my hack it won't work because the addres has changed. Is there a way that my program could automatically find the right address because I always have to find it manually and change it in the code.

I tried looking it up but couldn't find anything.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    int moneyAdress = 0xF4OAE;
    int customMoneyValue = 10000;

    DWORD money = (DWORD)moneyAdres;
    HWND wind = FindWindowA(NULL, "Roblox");

    DWORD procID;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(wind, &procID);
    HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCES, FALSE, procID);

    WriteProcessMemory(handle, (PBYTE*)money, &customMoneyValue, sizeoff(customMoneyValue), 0);

    return 0;
 }
```

So does anyone know how I could make it find the addresses on its own. Or is that impossible?

Comment: Cheat Engine is open source, presumably you could study the code and copy whatever they are doing.

Comment: You need to find a way to scan for memory patterns and then go from there.

Comment: @Rietty thanks I will try

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're finding a dynamic address not a static one.

Since this address is not static, a pointer is storing that address from one memory region to another one in some situations: game restarting, moving to another map, at all, it's making actions that force the game to reallocate memory.

If you find the pointer that aims to that address then you will get your value everytime, doesn't matters what you're doing. Only if the game code changes it will affects you.

Finding pointers it's not easy for a begginer but it's not hard.

Explaining all of this could take me days so my best way to help you is with the introduction above, and giving you my source of knowledge: youtube channel "Cheat the game"

I could guide you with clicks how to make pointer scans with pointer maps, but this is something that you have to understand from A to Z and this is a website for learning not for script kiddies, so I hope this helps you :)